# Is there any way to generate an Avro schema from a hashmap of values?

Tags: java, avro, parquet

We are putting all our data points for one row into a hashmap.  We don't want to use a pojo because the values are a different set each time.  For example, we might get "place" on some records and we might get "hometown" on others.  Actually we have thousands of different column names to choose from.  Our code looks like this:

```
Map<String, Object> aMap = new HashMap<>();
aMap.put("id", Integer.valueOf(1));
aMap.put("age", Integer.valueOf(45));
aMap.put("name", "mark");
aMap.put("place", "home");

final GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema);
aMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
  record.put(k, v);
});

writer.write(record);
```

We would like to put all the values in a map and then generate a schema.  Since using the Reflect api, it can be done for a pojo, I was wondering if it could be done from a hashmap as well?

As a side question, Is there any way to eliminate the forEach above and just write the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we came up with.  We also had nested columns.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser;
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Type;
/**
     * This does NOT do all types.  So far just the types we think we need.  See
     * https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.1.3.0/GettingStartedGuide/avroschemas.html
     * <p>
     * We need some error handlling here and when we don't have the correct type, call it out!
     * <p>
     * This runs in 1-2ms even with a large payload.
     */
    public class AvroSchemaBuilder {
    
      /**
       * Construct!
       */
      private AvroSchemaBuilder() {
        //private constructor.  All methods are static.
      }
    
      /**
       * Build the Avro schema and return it.
       *
       * @param name Name of object.
       * @param nameTypeConsumer The nameTypeConsumer of objects being saved.
       * @return the Avro schema.
       */
      public static Schema getAvroSchema(String name, NameTypeConsumer nameTypeConsumer) {
    
        String json = Lson.toJson(getAvroSchemaAsMap(name, nameTypeConsumer, true));
        Parser parser = new Parser().setValidate(true);
        return parser.parse(json);
      }
    
      /**
       * Returns the map with all the attributes to build a schema. This would be recursive if we need
       * to build a complex schema. For example for Trends this would build a complex schema where some
       * of the types are maps that are themselves described as another nested schema.
       */
      private static Map<String, Object> getAvroSchemaAsMap(String name,
                                                            NameTypeConsumer nameTypeConsumer,
                                                            boolean addNameSpace) {
        Map<String, Object> schemaMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        schemaMap.put("type", "record");
        schemaMap.put("name", name);
        if (addNameSpace) {
          schemaMap.put("namespace", "com.blah.blah");
        }
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList();
        nameTypeConsumer.consumeNestedNameType((columnName, nestedNameType) -> {
          Object avroType;
    
          if (nestedNameType.getNameTypeConsumer() != null) {
            avroType = getAvroSchemaAsMap(columnName, nestedNameType.getNameTypeConsumer(), false);
          } else {
            avroType = getAvroType(nestedNameType.getType()).getName();
          }
          Object[] types = {"null", avroType}; //adding null first always.
          fields.add(new Field(columnName, types));
        });
        schemaMap.put("fields", fields);
    
        return schemaMap;
      }
    
      /**
       * Finds the avro type by class.
       *
       * @param type the Type (this is an avro type).
       * @return avro constant.
       */
      private static Type getAvroType(Class<?> type) {
        if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
          return Type.INT;
        }
        if (type.equals(Long.class)) {
          return Type.LONG;
        }
        if (type.equals(Float.class)) {
          return Type.FLOAT;
        }
        if (type.equals(Double.class)) {
          return Type.DOUBLE;
        }
        if (type.equals(String.class)) {
          return Type.STRING;
        }
        if (type.equals(Boolean.class)) {
          return Type.BOOLEAN;
        }
        throw new GenericRuntimeException("Cannot get Avro type for type " + type.getName());
      }
    
      /**
       * Nested class to make our field.
       */
      private static class Field {
    
        public final String name;
        public final Object[] type;
    
        public Field(String name, Object[] type) {
          this.name = name;
          this.type = type;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: hi, I find this answer really useful for me. Could u explain a little bit more about the nameTypeConsumer?